# List blocks created by a specific block plugin

Tags: posts, block-editor

One way is to list all the posts and search using `[has_block][1]` but it seems inefficient. Is there a faster way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to extend the wordpress rest api by adding a custom endpoint that filtered all the posts using `has_block`
and return the results.